# How to activate jax-rs ContextResolver and Application in non-servlet 3.0/non-Java EE 6

Tags: java, tomcat, jaxb, jetty, jax-rs

Java EE 6 provides a way to activate JAX-RS Application on startup.

The problem is I am (and certainly many of us are still) using web server not compliant to Java EE/Servlet 3.0 so that if we tried to use load-on-startup servlet mapping on a JAX-RS Application, the web server (at least that is the case for jetty) would croak

```
"class is not a servlet"
```

and hence refuse to load the Application.

The gist of the matter is - to load the contextresolver, the only way which can be done only is through the jax-rs Application subclass.

The method to activate Application subclass should work similarly both on Jetty and Tomcat/JBoss because I am using jetty for development (due to GWT - what else?) and Tomcat/JBoss for production. I wish to avoid writing different loaders for jetty and tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

There are exist already  implemented start up servlets and context listeners in jax-rs providers like cxf or resteasy, just read docs carefully